# Slideshows in elastic or fluid layouts?

Tags: css, wordpress, jquery, css-framework

I'm building a new WordPress TwentyTen child theme using the ElastiCSS framework ( http://elasticss.com/ ) and am trying to figure out the best way of using some sort of dynamic content slideshow.

**What is the best way to implement a slideshow in a fluid or elastic layout such that it remains proportional to the other items in the content area?** Should I even bother trying to obtain that? Or should I use like four different sizes in conjunction with something like the Less framework ( http://lessframework.com/ )?

Thanks!

(BTW, I've posted here because this was more of a "what's the best option" question than a "How do I program that?" question. If you think it would be more appropriate on SO, please move it there.)

Comment: Has your question been answered yet aendrew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery Plugins: http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins?type=48

I'm sure there's a slideshow that is automatically scalable.

**EDIT**

---

My apologies for a bad answer, allow me to elaborate.

Using a JQuery Slideshow, such as [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/WOWSlider-jQuery_Image_Slider), you can specify the dimensions to be percentages of the parent element, which would meet your requirements.

Having a SlideShow that is scalable isn't impossible to implement - though it may just take some innovation on your part to make it look like it belongs in your site.

Comment: That WOW Slider is pretty cool. I'm trying to implement Piecemaker2; I'll give that a shot if I can't get Piecemaker to work in terms of percentages.

Comment: Did that answer your question, or should I include more information?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented a responsive/fluid slideshow: http://blog.kiskolabs.com/post/5602656614/responsive-jquery-slideshow

Comment: Please post a precis as part of your answer... "link only" answers are not helpful in a Q&A